# How to search for specific words and values in a long string?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

Ok my objective is:

1.Read in a text file. e.g containing text like this, teacher/student/1/sn/2/3/4/5/9/f/tn/02/

2.pass it to a string.

3.then beable to extract different parts of the string and place them in different arrays.

The bit I dont know how to do is the extracting specific parts of the string?
Is it possible to search for / and to treat what comes after it as a specific peice of information until the next / is read?

Or perhaps there is a more efficient approach?

Help and advice sought

Kindest regards
Adrian

Answer (score 2):

If your strings always have separator, you can split them:

```
var string:String = "teacher/student/1/sn/2/3/4/5/9/f/tn/02/";
var parts:Array = string.split("/"); // ["teacher", "student", ...]
```

To search specific words, RegExp might be good:

```
var re:RegExp = /teacher|student/;
var match:Object = re.exec(string); //match[0] = "teacher"
```

Of course, check out the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much I shall start experimenting!

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) will help you. Also see methods of [String](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure string passed to program will not bee too large? If it's size for instance 1Gb, you'll have troubles with performance

Comment: I think it wont be that big, but thank you for pointing this out I will keep it in my mind should I have problems.